Why is my LED burning out?
I'm working on an LED Array Using the following LEDs:
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/723/XLamp_XE_G-3359588.pdf
I initially added a total of 13 LEDs of varying colors using LDD-1000L and H LED Drivers, a controller for 5 V PWM control, and a benchtop power supply.  Considering the potential for 4 A while driving all four channels, I turned my power supply to 4 amps and 24 volts. I started adjusting PWM levels to make the LEDs brighter and several of the LEDs have burned out and are no longer working.
So I used a new PCB and had on PC Amber LED mounted to do some more testing on voltages and milliamps.
The schematic below details the circuit.

Here is the datasheet for that particular LED.

So, I connected directly from the benchtop supply and had my current set to 1 A, and slowly adjusted voltage to try and find the forward voltage.  I noticed that the LED would start to light up at 2.35 V and would start smoking/burning at 2.75 and higher. At the time, it was only receiving about 300-500mA of current.
Why is it doing this?  Do I need to add a voltage regulator or resistor in line with this LED's?

You should do some research for "current limiting for LEDs." This is one of the most basic and fundamental concepts with regard to driving LEDs. There are a multitude of questions about this.

How are you cooling the LEDs? Could you add a picture of your setup?

But is that not the purpose of using a Driver, It has a constant current?

Do you have your power supply in constant current mode? And if so, @Jonathan brings up a good point, are you cooling the LEDs?

@JonathanS. at this point they have no active cooling except for what the Fr-4 PCB provides.  For testing purposes, I figured this would suffice.  The final product will be attached to an aluminum PCB, attached to an aluminum heatsink with thermal grease between pieces.

@JYelton I dont think the power supply in constant current mode, I set the maximum before bringing up the voltage.

@blaineklein09yahoocom Please edit your question and add the relevant parts of the PCB layout so that we can check whether the LEDs are cooled sufficiently or not.

"try and find the forward voltage" you can get away with not properly de-heating a DUT when you keep duty cycle low and below thermal time constant.

Your schematic makes no sense. The constant-current LED driver is connected to the analogue input of the PWM controller? Provide an exact schematic, not something that's more like a block diagram. Also, what PWM controller? How is it controlled?

~1.3 W in a 2x1.6 mm package with no thermal management? I think @Jonathan S. got it here: you are not doing enough to remove the LED's heat. There is essentially no thermal mass to even let you get a brief test in before frying the tiny chip. The datasheet shows 2.4 C/W to the board, but even on a 10x10 mm footprint, you are still looking at >200 C/W to ambient. As usual, the manufacturer has a whitepaper for their specific product, but it sounds like you have planned for the heat in the finished product.

"it sounds like you have planned for the heat".  Have, or have not?

Aluminum PCB + heatsink sounds like it should be adequate if sized correctly.

First, as explained by vir, without adequate cooling these LEDs will overheat.
Second, although the schematic in the question is unreadable, I guess you used a PWM controller on the output of a constant current DC/DC converter. This won't work for the following reason:
On each PWM cycle, when the PWM goes off, it cuts current through the LEDs. Then the constant current driver simply does its job: it notices current is too low, it has no idea the LED PWM is actually off, so it increases its output voltage as hard and as fast as it can in an attempt to increase current back to the set value.
This doesn't work, of course, because the PWM is off, but this causes voltage on the output capacitor of the constant current DC/DC to ramp up. Then, the PWM switches on again, and dumps all the energy stored in the capacitor into the LED in one large current pulse, which can be much higher than the LED's maximum allowed current. This repeats on every cycle, until the LED burns.
Even if the DC/DC considers the average current, it will still attempt to do the opposite of what the PWM does. If you reduce the PWM to dim the LED... then the constant current driver will increase voltage to un-dim it. It just won't work.
If you want individual control on 13 LEDs, then you'd need a dimmable constant current DC/DC for each. This gets expensive quickly, and it takes a lot of space. On the plus side, it's efficient and your LEDs don't flicker.
The easiest solution is to check your LEDs Vf, if they're phosphor converted LEDs they should all be similar around 3V. So you need a constant voltage power supply a little bit above that, say 4V, one resistor per LED to set the current, and one MOSFET per LED to dim it using PWM.
To get the non-standard 3.something to 4V supply you can use a voltage output buck DC-DC converter for efficiency. But not a constant current output DC/DC.
And you absolutely need proper cooling.


would start smoking/burning

Doesn't that tell you that it's running way too hot?
You have to remove that heat or else it will keep on smoking and not working very long. That's all there's to it for now.
